# Call a .json from module.exports

Tags: discord.js, emoji, module.exports

To avoid having to change every emoji from every file whenever I switch an emoji, I decided to place an `emojis.json` and call the emoji from there.

emojis.json

```json
{
    "loading": "<a:loading:847653387343626301>",
    "pressf": "<:pressf:862166705911758909>"
}
```

Exampleping.js

```js
const emoji = require('../emojis.json')

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`${emoji.loading}Pong.`)
    }
}
```

Is this the right way? I'm open to new/better ideas.
Btw it errors: `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',`

Comment: SUMMARY: change path for emojis.json using ../ for every directory. Ty Salvino and Mohi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clean except your import statement is not referring to the `emojis.json` file. To make it more clear, the script failed to locate the file, which means emojis.json is not located inside the same directory as exampleping.js (`require('./emojis.js')`).

Based on my experience with Discord bot development, I believe you placed `emojis.json` in your root directory while `exampleping.js` is placed inside a directory commonly named "commands". With that being said, all you need is to exist the command directory by adding another `.` to `require()`.

```
      const emojis = require('../emojis.js');
      //instead of ./emojis.json
```

See [HTML File Path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Oh my bad, I realized I was referring to the answer above. But my point is still the same, the path inside `require` is invalid, which is what's causing the error

Comment: Yeah but I tried using many . and it doesn't work.
`emojis.js` path: main/emojis.js
`exampleping.js` path: main/commands/tests/exampleping.js

Comment: Well, then it's `../../../emojis.json` because `exampleping.js` is in a three-level directory

Comment: Thanks, worked with `../../emojis.json`
But it still doesn't show the emoji, it sends "undefinedPing"

Answer (score 2):

Well, your approach is correct to a certain extent. Only issue is that you have imported a `json` file instead of `js` file and hence it throws an error.

Correct way of achieving this, is having a `emojis.js` file with your json object exported using `module.exports`

```js
// emojis.js
module.exports = {
    loading: "<a:loading:847653387343626301>",
    pressf: "<:pressf:862166705911758909>"
};


// Exampleping.js
const emojis = require('../../emojis.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`${emoji.loading}Pong.`)
    }
}
```

Comment: .JSON files are meant to be import-able without using `module.exports`

Comment: You need a transpiler like `babel` for `json` files to be imported directly to your js file and to work correctly, if I'm not mistaken @Mohi.

Comment: Not working, same error.
Also I saw you changed `emoijs.json` to `emojis.js`, why is that?

Comment: Well if you don't have a transpiler like babel, your `require('emojis.json')` might not work. Hence it's always safer to import a `js` file which uses `module.exports` to export the json configuration. Also, if you're still facing error then it means it's not able to locate that file. Are both `emoji.js` & `exampleping.js` at the same directory level?

Comment: No, `emojis.js/json` is next to `index.js` (main/index.js). While `ping.js` is in main/commands/tests/exampleping.js

Comment: ah, please change the the path in the require and it will start working. I've updated it in the answer. Please check @Dharuz.

Comment: It's working now, thanks. But it says "undefinedPing"

Comment: It didn't work with .js, I had to change it back to .json and it works just fine now. Thanks.